# Formatting 2 arrays in JSON Auto

Tags: sql, json, auto

So I am doing work in a SQL environment and I need to create a JSON message. I am using JSON AUTO.

```
        SELECT 
    --Header
    header.load_id                  AS shipmentNumber,
    header.load_id                  AS tripNumber, 
    'TMS'                       AS tmsID,
    CASE WHEN header.status = '4' THEN 'CANCELED'  
         WHEN header.status = '2' THEN 'UPDATE'
         WHEN header.status = '0' THEN 'UPDATE'
         WHEN header.status = '3' THEN 'SHIPPED'
         WHEN header.status = '1' THEN 'CREATED'  
         ELSE 'UNKNOWN'         END AS purpose,
    header.insert_datetime          AS erpCreatedDateTime,
    'Outbound'                      AS movementType, 
    'PREPAID'                       AS freightTerms,
    header.status                   AS orderStatus, 
    'OBDRY'                         AS divisionCode, 
    header.total_pallets            AS palletPositions,
    --locations 
    locations.go_destination        AS locationID,
    locations.stop_sequence         AS stopSequenceNumber,
    locations.stoprole              AS stopRole,
    locations.go_name               AS name,
    locations.go_addr1              AS address1,
    locations.go_addr2              AS address2,
    locations.go_city               AS city, 
    locations.go_provcode           AS stateProvidenceCode,
    locations.go_postalcode         AS postalCode,
    locations.go_countrycode        AS countryCode, 
    locations.go_contact            AS contact,
    locations.go_phone              AS phone,
    locations.go_email              AS email,
    locations.estimated_datetime    AS estimatedDateTime,
    locations.scheduled_datetime    AS scheduledDateTime,
    'NA'                            AS truckArriveDateTime,
    locations.truckDepart_datetime  AS truckDepartDateTime,
    --items
    items.order_number              AS orderNumber,
    'Cases'                         AS packagingType,
    items.netWeight                 AS netWeight,
    items.volume                    AS volume,
    items.case_qty                  AS packageQuantity
    FROM t_export_outbound_load header
    INNER JOIN t_export_outbound_destination locations
    ON header.import_id = locations.import_id
    AND header.wh_id = locations.wh_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_export_outbound_order items
    ON header.import_id = items.import_id
    AND header.wh_id = items.wh_id
    WHERE header.import_id = @import_id
    FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('record')
```

Which creates a message like this

```
{
    "record": [
        {
            "shipmentNumber": "39177",
            "tripNumber": "39177",
            "tmsID": "TMS",
            "purpose": "CANCELED",
            "erpCreatedDateTime": "2022-04-20T12:07:14.753",
            "movementType": "Outbound",
            "freightTerms": "PREPAID",
            "orderStatus": "4",
            "divisionCode": "OBDRY",
            "palletPositions": 1,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "locationID": 716,
                    "stopSequenceNumber": 2,
                    "truckArriveDateTime": "NA",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "GO000381427",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "GO000383300",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "GO000382780",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "GO000382781",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "GO000383200",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "GO000383201",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "HJ166490",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 29
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "locationID": 720,
                    "stopSequenceNumber": 1,
                    "truckArriveDateTime": "NA",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "GO000381427",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "GO000383300",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "GO000382780",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "GO000382781",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "GO000383200",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "GO000383201",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "orderNumber": "HJ166490",
                            "packagingType": "Cases",
                            "packageQuantity": 29
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However it is nesting the Items array inside each Locations result. I would like to arrange it so that it's got the Locations Array, followed by the Items array.

Does anyone have any suggestions?